# MS-Access (Forms): allow user to enter invalid data in a bound, typed TextBox, with intent of correcting it programmatically. How?

Tags: ms-access

I am in the habit of typing date/times in a YYYYMMDDHHmmss format without separators, e.g. "20110807050000" and I want to rig my "date" TextBoxes in an Access form to allow me to enter dates this way.

The TextBoxes in question are databound to Table fields that are of Date/Time type.

The way I have chosen to approach this is just to parse what I type and if I can get a valid date-time out of it, stick it back in the text box. The parsing etc. is complete and ready to go but I am stuck figuring out how to wire it into the form.

Normally (I think .. access/VBA is a bit rusty ..) I would use "BeforeUpdate" event of a control to handle this kind of thing but the problem here is the Form is triggering its default validation error 2113 "the value you entered isn't valid for this field" before it even gets around to running the Control-level events.

Then when I tried parsing/updating the TextBox in the Form_Error procedure, i get a 2115 error "The macro or function set to the BeforeUpdate or ValidationRule property of this field is preventing [...] saving the data in the field." In the Control.BeforeUpdate scenario, I think you can use the "Cancel" flag to get around this sort of hang-up, but Form.OnError event doesn't have anything like that (at least "Response" doesn't seem to be doing the trick.)

edit-just to be complete: I also occasionally might *want* to use traditional "MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss [AM/PM]" (or similar) form, and also that I already have parsing in place for pasting dates off the clipboard in another "common" format (the one used in Windows Explorer's Properties dialog), and would like this capability to remain, and remain extendable.

Kinda stumped. Figured I would ask around a bit before resorting to some really invasive/ugly hack to get this working.

Thanks for reading! Any suggestions/solutions are appreciated!

Comment: You can't do what you want to do with a bound textbox, because one of the main "features" of the data binding is that it validates the data for you. You'll have to use an unbound textbox for this.

Comment: @David TY! No way, huh? Well, moving onward ... I suppose there are enough tutorials to be found about doing this sort of juggling - e.g. something nasty like adding an additional locked, databound TB and updating it via code, while user activity takes place in an unbound TB. I will post back with what I come up with, but in the meantime, if anyone has any "hot" links on the subject...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to-date:

Created an additional unbound TextBox to do my data-entry in.

UnboundTextBox.OnLostFocus I try to parse a valid date out of what has been entered and, if a valid date is the outcome, insert that in the original bound TextBox for the field (now Locked).

Form.OnCurrent I copy whatever is in the bound TextBox to the unbound one, to ease editing of existing data.

Pretty basic, and pretty nasty, but, as it's an app for personal use, it's workable, and I've basically already grown accustomed to seeing the extra TextBox on the screen. (I suppose it could be hidden, but I started with it Visible, for debugging purposes, and just left it that way, so far.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BeforeUpdate you can use the KeyDown event and have it respond to Enter, Tab, PgUp, and PgDn. This will execute code when you leave the field or record but before validation (what BeforeUpdate SHOULD do). The only drawback is that the code won't run if you use the mouse to leave the field.

I used this to to convert directions like N, NE, WSW to degrees in an integer field. It isn't perfect but is good enough.